# .NET System.CommandLine: invoking command via Parser doesn't write to console, whereas command.Invoke does

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a console application that uses `System.CommandLine` to parse arguments and options.

To be able to deal with exceptions better, I've switched from RootCommand.Invoke(args) to using a CommandLineBuilder like this:

```
    CommandLineBuilder oCLB = new(oRootCmd);
    oCLB.UseExceptionHandler((e, c) => LogExceptionAndRaiseEvent(e));
    Parser oPrs = oCLB.Build();
    int iRC = oPrs.Invoke(p_StartupArgs);
```

Now I've noticed that this way of invoking doesn't write to the console anymore, neither when there is a parsing error nor when being called with the default help switch "-h".

I suspect it has to do with the second parameter in Invoke, which is can be an IConsole (and is NULL by default), but I don't have a real clue and wouldn't know what to pass there.

**UPDATE:** see solution below, using some CommandLineBuilder configuration options.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.commandline.io.systemconsole?view=system-commandline

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding this in the form of `int iRC = oPrs.Invoke(p_StartupArgs, new SystemConsole());` unfortunately doesn't have an effect, either @Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, the solution was adding some more "Use" configuration to the `CommandLineBuilder`:

```
      CommandLineBuilder oCLB = new(oRootCmd);
      oCLB.UseHelp().
        UseVersionOption().
        UseParseErrorReporting();
      oCLB.UseExceptionHandler((e, c) => BygLog.LogExceptionAndRaiseEvent(e));
      Parser oPrs = oCLB.Build();
      int iRC = oPrs.Invoke(p_StartupArgs, new SystemConsole());
```

As per https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues/2188

Comment: Update your question every time you want to add new info